# Most efficient way to pull values that may or may not change?

Tags: database, vba, function, reference, cursor-position

I am not a trained programmer, but I assist in developing/maintaining macros within our VBA-based systems to expedite various tasks our employees do manually. For instance, copying data from one screen to another. By hand, any instance of this could take 30 seconds to 2 minutes, but with a macro, it could take 2-3 seconds.

Most of the macros we develop rely on the ability to accurately pull data as displayed (not from its relative field!) based on a row/column format for each character. As such, we employ the use of a custom command (let's call it, say... Instance.Grab) that pulls what we need from the screen using row x/column y coordinates and the length of what we want to pull. Example, where the we would normally pull a 8 character string from coordinates 1,1:

```
dim PulledValue as String
PulledValue = Instance.Grab(1,1,8)
```

If I ran that code on my question so far, the returned value for our macro would have been "I am not"

Unfortunately, our systems are getting their displays altered to handled values of an increased character length. As such, the coordinates of the data we're pulling is getting altered significantly. Rather than go through our macros and change the coordinates and length manually in each macro (which would need to be repeated if the screen formats change again), I'm converting our macros so that any time they need to pull the needed string, we can simply change the needed coordinate/length from a central location.

My question is, what would be the best way to handle this task? I've thought of a few ideas, but want to maximize effectiveness and minimize the time I spend developing it, given my limited programming experience. For the sake of this, let's call what I need to make happen CoorGrab, and where an array is needed, make an array called CoorArray:

1) creating Public Function CoorGrab(ThisField As Variant) -if I did it this way, than I would simply list all the needed coordinate/length sets based on the variant I enter, then pull whichever set as needed using a 3 dimensional array. For instance: CoorGrab(situationA) would return CoorArray(5, 7, 15). This would be easy enough to edit for one of us who know something about programming, but if we're not around for any reason, there could be issues.

2) creating all the needed coordinates in public arrays in the module. I'm not overly familiar with how to implement this, but I think I read up on something called public constants? I kinda like this idea for its simplicity, but am hesitant to use any variable or array as public.

3) creating a .txt file in a shared drive that has all the needed data and a label to identify them, and save it to a shared drive that any terminal can access when running these macros. This would be the easiest for a non-programmer to jump in and edit in case I or one of our other programming-savvy employees aren't available, but it seems like far more work than is needed, and I fear what could happen if the .txt file got a type or accidentally deleted.

Any thoughts on how I should proceed? Are one of the above options inherently better/easier than the others? Or is there another way to handled this situation that I didn't cover? Any info or advice you all can provide would be greatly appreciated!

8/2/15 Note - Should probably mention the VBA is used as part of a terminal emulator with custom applications for the needs of our department. I don't manage the emulator or its applications, nor do I have system admin access; I just create/edit macros used within it to streamline some of the ways our users handle their workloads. Of the three of us who do this, I'm the least skilled at programming, but also the only on who could be pulled that could update them before the changes take effect.

Comment: The answer to this depends on a bunch of things, many of which are not in your question. For example it's not clear whether the definition for any given field needs to be shared across different workbooks, or how many total definitions you will have.  Also, how you currently manage your VBA (distributing updates etc) will also impact the "best" way to achieve what you want.  Having the definitions stored in an external file seems like the way to go.  Make it read-only for anyone but your team if you're worried about accidental updates.

Comment: Luckily, no real workbooks involved. Everyone can customize their session of the application we use; all we did was create a session with these macros and stored it in a company-shared drive. Then anyone interested in using the macros just needs to load a reference to that file. That way, all changes can be made only to that file and everyone gets access to the updates.

As far definitions, there's about 200-300 of them. More may be added if we need additional definitions. Read-only isn't an option for the emulator though; we tried it and it prevented access to the macros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your way is not so bad, I would:

- Use a string as a label as parameter for CoorGrab
- Return a range instead of a string (because you can use a single cell range as text and you keep a trace where your data is)

`public CoorGrab(byval label as string) as range`

- Create an Excel Sheet with 3 rows: 1 = label, 2 = x, 3 = y (you could
  add a 4 if you need to search in an other sheet)
- CoorGrab() `Find` the label in the Excel Sheet and return X / Y

If developers aren't availables, they just have to edit the Excel sheet.
You could too create and outsource Excel File to read coordinates outside the local file, or use it to update files of everybody (Read file from server, add/update all label in the server file but not in local file)

Comment: I've only touched a bit on utilizing Excel, and it's a mixed bag since our applications are custom made using a commercial terminal emulator. I'm not sure how to make the session that has our macros utilize a closed excel workbook, and even if I did, we'd have to go terminal to terminal and update their personal sessions to to reference the Windows Excel Object Library just to make them use it. Sadly, can't make Excel a viable option. There a way to do what you mentioned using a .txt file?

Comment: The second excel is just to be use like a document (no macro and it can be update easily by everyone), it's like a txt file. But if you don't feel confortable with, you could use a csv file instead, it will do the same work and it's a txt file.

You edit your csv under Excel (create 3 columns), save it under csv format, and you can use the method I describe in the answer to return result

Comment: Unfortunately, any standard Excel document is still unusable unless we updated everyone's terminal AND saved sessions to reference the Excel Object Library; this isn't a default reference in our systems, and there's just way too many ways peoples' sessions could fall through the cracks. HOWEVER... that .csv file sounds like it would be the perfect fit for the job! I have yet to test it in our system, but everything I read indicates the software should be able to use it easily... and since Excel can read/edit them, it would make updates a breeze! Will post update when I can implement. Thanks!

Comment: The csv format worked like a charm! Took us a bit to make it easy to reference but easy for our non-programmers to format when needed, but it's a thing of beauty! Thank you Maxime!